# How to move populated cells in rows with nan values to last no-nan row in the same cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So this is a kind of strange question. Essentially, I've got a df that looks like this:

| game | platform |
| --- | --- |
| a | nintendo |
| nan | ps4 |
| nan | xbox |
| b | ps4 |
| c | ps4 |
| nan | xbox |

When I have nan for the game that means that really that platform should've been in the last non-nan games platform column. So the above should really be:

| game | platform |
| --- | --- |
| a | nintendo, ps4, xbox |
| b | ps4 |
| c | ps4, xbox |

I tried putting together a quick solution:

```
cache = set()
last_non_nan = 0

def compress(row):
    global last_non_nan
    global cache
    
    if (type(row['Name']) != type("")) and math.isnan(row['Name']):
        cache.add(row['Platforms'])
        
    elif not cache:
        for item in cache:
            print(atvi_games.at[last_non_nan, 'Platforms'])
            atvi_games.at[last_non_nan, 'Platforms'] += item
            
        last_non_nan = row.name
        cache.clear()
```

It doesn't work. Even if it did, I can't help feeling that there is some simple way of doing this that I'm not seeing. Anybody have any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `nan` to `numpy.nan`, if it is a string:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan, regex=True)
```

If `nan` is already `np.nan`, use [`Series.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [2001]: df.game = df.game.ffill()
In [2005]: x = df.groupby('game').agg(','.join).reset_index()

In [2006]: x
Out[2006]: 
  game           platform
0    a  nintendo,ps4,xbox
1    b                ps4
2    c           ps4,xbox
```

Comment: I should have clarified originally, but there are also other columns that are similar to the game one. Meaning there are columns that are nan in the row with runoff platforms, but non nan in the previous rows. Your method works very well, but I lose all other information.

Comment: Sorted it out with the following!
```
x = atvi_games.groupby('Name').agg({'Year': 'first', 'Platforms': lambda x: ','.join(x)}).reset_index()
``` Thank you for the lead!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `groupby`:

```
# if `nan` is np.nan
# use `df['game'].notna().cumsum()
(df.groupby(df['game'].ne('nan').cumsum(), as_index=False)
   .agg({'game':'first', 'platform':','.join})
)
```

Output:

```
  game           platform
0    a  nintendo,ps4,xbox
1    b                ps4
2    c           ps4,xbox
```